# Access Text Boxes (in a Keynote slide) in AppleScript

Tags: cocoa, textbox, applescript, slide, keynote

Need some help to figure out how to access Text Boxes inside a slide in Keynote with Applescript. I tried to use ASDictionary but I couldn't find anything that would resemble a text box object. I fear that they are not scriptable in Keynote, but perhaps I can access them through Applescript Cocoa bridge? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: An application's entire AppleScript interface is in its dictionary—that's what the dictionary is for. And the Scripting Bridge is merely a different way of doing the same things.

Comment: You may want to ask a separate question with exactly what you want to do that you'd hoped to do with AppleScript.

Comment: It is rather simple, perhaps I should have worded it differently: How to access textboxes of a keynote document through applescript or applescript cocoa bridge :)

Comment: That part was clear. What isn't is what you want to do with the text boxes.

Comment: word count, the way I have it now, word count is reliable only for slide notes.

Comment: IIRC, slide objects have title and body properties; beyond that, I'd need to dig up a copy. The iWork apps all have spectacularly badly designed scripting interfaces, mind.

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) Keynote doesn't provide access to objects on a slide via AppleScript, then you should do two things:

1. File an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com/ .
2. Try examining the Keynote document directly by parsing its XML.

Keynote's XML document format is not documented, as far as I know, but at least you can access it. You just have to be careful about the format changing out from under you.

Comment: I think it is documented here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/iWork2-0_XML/Chapter02/02Pages.html. XML parsing was on my mind but I decided against it.